# getContentResolver().query issue

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Both of these are leaking my activity, When its exceeds 1mb heap memory. I need to delete more than 1mb conacts i,e; above 2500 contacts.

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
Cursor cur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

What is an alternative or work around? 
Then I do

```
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            cr.delete(uri, null, null);             
        } while (cur.moveToNext());    
    }
    cur.close();
```

How can I only delete 100-200 contacts at a time? or any other way?

Log:

```
03-02 14:26:57.317: E/CursorWindow(5357): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 216, freeSpace() = 135, numRows = 2616
03-02 14:26:57.317: E/CursorWindow(5357): not growing since there are already 2616 row(s), max size 1048576
03-02 14:26:57.317: E/CursorWindow(5357): The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot 2615
03-02 14:26:57.317: E/Cursor(5357): Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0 row 2615
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Loader to run the query on a separate thread. This is documented in the Developers Guide under Loaders. By the way, managedQuery() has been deprecated.

You should *never* run a query directly on an Activity. You'll hang everything pretty quickly.

You also ask about deleting contacts, although I don't see any code that does this.

To do this, you should delete them with ContentProviderOperation objects and 
ContentResolver.applyBatch(). Unless you want to do it in a big hurry, mark each of the
ContentProviderOperation objects with "yield allowed".

ArrayList oparray = new ArrayList;

objBuilder = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
objBuilder.withYieldAllowed(true);
obj = objBuilder.build();

oparray.add(obj);

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, oparray);

This is going to be slow, depending on how much Contacts data there is.

Comment: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> oparray = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
  //ArrayList oparray = new ArrayList;
  ContentProviderOperation.Builder objBuilder = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
  objBuilder.withYieldAllowed(true);
  //objBuilder.withExpectedCount(12);
  ContentProviderOperation obj = objBuilder.build();
  oparray.add(obj);
  
  oparray.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .build());

Comment: Plus ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, oparray);`

Comment: This is not deleting any contacts.

Comment: You should really wrap your code with tags. Makes it much easier to follow your answer!